# "Environment theorem* undefined"

Tags: errors, amsthm

Consider the following LaTeX2e manuscript

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem*}[Hello World]
Hello, world!
\end{theorem*}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with `pdflatex`, the compilation fails with the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment theorem* undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{theorem*}
                    [Hello World]
?
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: The asterisk?? maybe?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, you're right. I thought the presence of an asterisk is supposed to indicate that the theorem should not be numbered. Apparently this doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: You can use `\newtheoremstyle*{lem}{Lemma}`, but the documentation never states that a sudden `lem*` would work.

Comment: You can add`\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}`to your preamble.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I thought the asterisk worked like a macro option. I was wrong.